# Is there a faster way to backup and restore for mysql?

Tags: mysql, backup, database-restore

Sql Server and Oracle have commercial products like Idera (Sql Safe) and Quest (LiteSpeed) that dramatically speed up backup and restores.

Does mysql have any commercial software like that?

I'm working with large amounts of data in mysql and if we have to restore it takes 8-10 hours. So I'm hoping to move to a commercial product that can do it faster.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @deobert - understand where you are coming from but as a developer supporting my application that stores a crap-ton of information, I thought it was a valid question... as I may have to change the application simply because of limitations on the db (due to necessary recovery limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a commercial option works for you, check out [InnoDB Hot Backup](http://www.innodb.com/hot-backup/features/).  They say that 
backup time is comparable to file copy time and recovery is faster.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Backup & Restore Databases Software 7.0](http://download.cnet.com/MySQL-Backup-Restore-Databases-Software/3000-10254_4-127600.html) is one, but **Restoring a backup** is mostly a long series of INSERT statements so you check here for tips on improving performance [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start).  It is still alpha, but according to the [last release announcement](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/13/xtrabackup-03-binaries-and-stream-backup/) it "shows perfect stable results in our tests".

I have not tried it to know the performance, but it appears to be more low-level than the sql output that mysqldump generates.

Answer (score 0):

Online backups are not exactly what you are looking for. The tools out there that exist for MySQL don't provide a lot of functionality that other DBMS vendors have. If you enable MySQL binary logs you can have "point in time" recovery. However, the initial load will still take forever.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/point-in-time-recovery.html